# MFC: How to loop through each CMap item and update it?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a loop to adjust the value used in an MFC CMap variable.  But how do I update the value within the loop?

```
    pos=m_MyMap.GetStartPosition();
    while (pos!=NULL) {
      // get reference to key and value of next item
      uint16_t key;
      uint32_t indexref;
      m_MyMap.GetNextAssoc(pos, key, indexref);
      // check if index needs adjusting
      if (static_cast<INT_PTR>(indexref)>indexremoved) {
        indexref--;
        // ****** HOW TO UPDATE? ****
      }
    }
```

TIA!!

Comment: Your update should be an answer, not an edit. Please revert your edit and post an answer instead.

Comment: I changed it, but frankly, I think the whole point and score thing is dumb.  I think it should just be questions and answers, like back in the old MS public. newsgroup days many resulting in MSKB article, but MS for some dumb reason has removed them, even as storage as gotten cheap (I'd have archived and hosted them if I even had the remote thought they would remove them).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
    pos=m_MyMap.GetStartPosition();
    while (pos!=NULL) {
      // get reference to key and value of next item
      uint16_t key;
      uint32_t indexref;
      m_MyMap.GetNextAssoc(pos, key, indexref);
      // check if index needs adjusting
      if (static_cast<INT_PTR>(indexref)>indexremoved) {
        indexref--;
        // ****** HERE'S HOW TO UPDATE ****
        m_MyMap[key]=indexref;
      }
    }
```